# VSE: Use png images in one channel as alpha mask for another channel

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency, masking

I have rendered a 2D animation from Synfig as png images. It put out the png image of each frame and also the alpha values of each frame as separate png. (basically a white silouette of the animated shape with a black background).

However, I cannot find a way to use the alpha pngs as transparency mask in Blender's VSE (Blender Version 2.79 on Windows 10). I loaded both strips of images in separate channels but can't find a Blend mode that subtracts one from the other. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it is a bit hidden.

I have three strips here, a blue one which serves as the background, an orange one as foreground and the black and white at the bottom to use as alpha channel.

The orange strip on top is supposed to get the mask. In order to do that, it needs a Mask Modifier with the Black & white strip as its source.

After that, simply select 'Alpha Over' as the blend type for the top strip.

[image]

The alpha mask:

[image]

What you get with the default blend type (Cross):

[image]

The finished result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that did the trick! For other noobs like me I will clarify that the alpha strip (black&white) needs to be at the bottom, as you did it. I naively just put it anywhere.

Comment: One is glad to be of service.

Comment: By the way, you CAN put it anywhere if you hide it with H or by clicking it's eye in the 'Edit Strip' panel. The alpha effect will still work while the strip itself will be hidden.